# Would a golfer say, "I shot for 200 yards"?

Tags: prepositions

I'm wondering if "for" is the correct word to use in the phrase, "I shot for 200 yards".

This is in relation to a golf video game I'm working on. After the shot, the computer tells you, "You shot for 200 yards!" to inform you how far the ball went.

Comment: Omitting the word changes the meaning of the sentence. What do you want it to mean?

Comment: Maybe you can also try asking at http://sports.stackexchange.com

Comment: sounds like something an American teenager might say. How about, "Your shot went 200 yards." or "You hit a 200 yard drive." or "You drove 200 yards."

Comment: I think it would sound more natural to say, "You hit the ball 200 yards", or "You hit it 200 yards".

Comment: Not unless he's a liar.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, @GEdgar; sports terminology questions are generally on topic on both sites and can stay on whichever site they are asked on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To "Shoot for X" is an idiomatic expression meaning that you are trying to achieve a specific goal, X.  Thus if the computer tells me "you shot for 200 yards", I would expect the follow-up to be "and came within 10 yards of it" or "but overshot by 50 yards" or some such measure of how successful I was at achieving the desired goal.

I doubt that this is your intended meaning, so I'd have to say that "You hit the shot 200 yards" or "Your drive went 200 yards" would be better expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few written instances showing that a golfer is often said to...

> [***drive*** 200 yards](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golfer%20drove%20200%20yards%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22golfer%22%20%22drive%20200%20yards%22&tbm=bks)
>    (or [***hit*** a 200 yard drive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golfer%20drove%20200%20yards%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22hit%20a%20200%20yard%20drive%22&tbm=bks))

The past tense might sound slightly odd to non-golfers, but they [*drove 200 yards*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22golfer%20drove%20200%20yards%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22golf%22%20%22drove%20200%20yards%22&tbm=bks) too. There wouldn't normally be a preposition though (***for*** implies driving a car or golf cart/buggy).

Comment: Would it be acceptable to say "I hit a shot for 200 yards?" wrt golf.

Comment: @Matt: I suppose it's "acceptable", but it sounds a bit "busy" to me by comparison with *"I drove/hit 200 yards"*. Also I'm not sure golfers normally use "shot" like that - it's a ***drive*** (long distance), or a ***putt*** (short distance).

Comment: @Matt: No, I've never heard that. It's **hit** or **drive** 200 yards. Though it'd rather be `hit` since 200 yards is rather short for a drive (no pun intended).

Comment: @okiharaherbst: That just shows how much I know about golf! I see now I'd have got far more results on the links in my answer if I'd changed it to ***300*** yards! (Not so many can make 400 yards though! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: golfers communicate mostly in a very, very rich lingo (and politically incorrect jokes) that is only comparable in depth to that of Wall Street's stock brokers. Actually, another noteworthy point is that you may only say _drive_ if you're referring the first shot (the tee-off). Otherwise it's always _hit_, irrespective of the distance. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_golf.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Lastly, some oddities end up being named after those who perpetrated them, e.g. a _Mulligan_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulligan_(games)).

Comment: @MattЭллен "I hit a 200-yard shot." "I hit a shot 200 yards."

Answer (score 3):

A golfer says "I shot a (score)".  (Score) being their score for the round.  They do not "shot" a distance.  For that you can say:

> I drove the ball about 200 yards today.
>
> I had a drive (or shot but less common) that went 200 yards.
>
> I hit the ball over 200 yards.